# Receiving user input and uses the input for a different task in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted to make a command in discord.py where when the command was activated(such as h!start in this case), it would ask the user to input the amount of minutes it would like to receive a reminder and the program would send a reminder in x amount of minutes.

I have the code for the reminder, I just don't know how to make it so a user can input a specific period of time.

```
@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    global start_channel
    start_channel = ctx.channel.id
    channel = client.get_channel(int(start_channel))
    reminder.start()
    await channel.send('Reminder Started')



@tasks.loop(minutes=5) #the amount of minutes should be able to be set by the user
async def reminder():
    channel = client.get_channel(int(start_channel))
    await channel.send('It has been 5 minutes.')


@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    channel = client.get_channel(int(start_channel))
    reminder.cancel()
    await channel.send('Reminder stopped. Thanks for using!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to get user input would be to include it in the call of the function. For example `h!start 5` to start the function and set the timer to 5 minutes.
To achieve this you should change the function header to the following:

```
async def start(ctx, input: int):
```

Then you can use `asyncio.sleep(input)` to sleep for the amount of time you want instead of using a decorator.

Comment: This didn't do anything, there was no error but the program still messaged after 5 minutes even though I did h!start 1

Comment: Try awaiting the call. `await asyncio.sleep(input)`

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by that? I am new to python

Comment: discord.py is a library that uses _coroutines_ , basically it is a generalisation of _subroutines_ , they can be entered, exitedd and resumed at many points. The keyword `await` passes function control back to the event loop, so it needed when using coroutines. In this case to make it work your function shall have the header that I added in my post and it should call `await asyncio.sleep(input)` to start waiting X seconds. (input should be in seconds as well)